# Where does punta music originate from?

Tags: musicology

I know bachata comes from the Dominican Republic.

Which country does punta music originate from?

Comment: Possibly Belize and/or Honduras: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta

Answer (score 4):

Punta is a Garifuna music and dance style performed at celebrations and festive occasions. Created by the Garifuna people of St. Vincent best known to derive from Honduras, El Salvador, Belize, Guatemala, and parts of Nicaragua, so Central America. Hope that helps.